# GroovyServlet returning 404 on all requests after successfully loading once?

Tags: tomcat, groovy

I have a Groovy script in the root of my web application being served by Tomcat 7.0.22. The script is being served by GroovyServlet from Groovy 1.8.4. When I start the application, via Tomcat's "manager" application, I can send a request to the script and get back a 200. *Without changing anything* I can send a second request and get back a 404. Every request after the first request results in a 404 until I restart the application. The only thing written to the Catalina.out log is:

```
GroovyServlet Error:  script: '/test.groovy':  Script not found, sending 404.
```

How do I either 1) resolve this problem or 2) go about debugging it? I looked through the [GroovyServlet source code](http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=groovy-git.git;a=blob;f=src/main/groovy/servlet/GroovyServlet.java;h=5c84bb388699ab9c22003e833d205a850affb1ce;hb=HEAD) for any possible web.xml configuration parameters for debugging, but I don't see any.

To be clear, my application's web directory is:

```
/test.groovy
/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
/WEB-INF/groovy/classes*.groovy
/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: Appears bug has been fixed in Groovy 2.0.6. Download and check it out!

Answer (score 1):

The GroovyServlet should allow the .groovy scripts to be placed in either web application's normal web root or in /WEB-INF/groovy/. However, I've seen a couple of times where scripts are not resolved if in the web root. Try moving the *.groovy* scripts to /WEB-INF/groovy/ and restart Tomcat.

This is the configuration I use to deploy groovy scripts in both Tomcat and Google App Engine. Works normally with Groovy 1.8.4 through 2.0.1, however, I'm seeing some issues with Groovy 2.0.2, 2.0.4, and 2.0.5 not resolving scripts as you describe. I will continue to use Groovy 2.0.1 until the GroovyServlet errors are fixed.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/servlet/GroovyServlet.html

**UPDATE:** The bug described above with groovy scripts in web root or /WEB-INF/groovy has been fixed in Groovy 2.0.6.

Comment: The structure of my application relied on being able to place .groovy scripts in the webroot. Thus, moving them all to WEB-INF/groovy would not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: this is an epic bug. It seems very strange to me this not covered with tests.

Answer (score 0):

Changing line 501/491 in Groovy 1.8.8/2.0.2 in groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine from

`String path = conn.getURL().toExternalForm();`

to

`String path = conn.getURL().getPath();`

fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Please report that to the bug tracker ticket linked in the comments of the other answer.

Comment: I would, but I can't just create an account - I have to contact the admins first. That way was faster ;-)